# How compatible is python with an python:alpine docker image?

Tags: python, performance, docker, compatibility, alpine-linux

I am using python:3.8-slim for my python application, but I am seeing that it takes up a lot of space compared to python:alpine.

I prefer use python:3.8-slim because I think there is not enough compatibility between python and alpine, It is something like what is discussed in this article https://pythonspeed.com/articles/alpine-docker-python/

what do you think guys?

Answer (score 0):

There is no compatibility issues using alpine vs slim. You'll have pip to install all the other dependencies.

The problem comes when you need some core dependency from debian or ubuntu, but alpine has apk add [Here's the example](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Alpine_Linux_package_management)